# Subscript out of range, array variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner at VBA and I've been scratching my head all day trying to figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
Sub DataTransfer():
    Dim position As Integer, location (1 To 9) As String
    location(1) = "BC"
    location(2) = "Calgary"
    location(3) = "Edmonton"
    location(4) = "Major Projects"
    location(5) = "Minneapolis"
    location(6) = "Saskatchewan"
    location(7) = "Seattle"
    location(8) = "Toronto"
    location(9) = "Winnipeg"

    For position = 1 To 9
        Worksheets(location(position)).Select
        Cells(1, 2).Value = location(position)
    Next position
End Sub
```

Edit: Sorry about the ambiguity of my question. What I ultimately want to do is actually to be able to change that third last line (that writes the city name to the worksheets) to any function I want so as to modify the worksheets as I see fit. This is actually part of a larger subroutine that I broke out to troubleshoot the problem. These worksheets are interspersed between other worksheets so unfortunately, @nutsch's solution won't really achieve what I want (but thanks either way).

The biggest problem I have with this is that this exact code would sometimes work as intended and other times return the "subscript out of range" error on the fourth last line.

Comment: Are you sure all your worksheets are named properly?

Comment: What line were you getting this error on?

Comment: What is your code SUPPOSED to do?  Because right now it is looking for sheets called "BC", "Calgary", "Edmonton", etc and changing the value of the cell(1, 2) on that sheet to the name of the sheet.  @nutsch solution below would accomplish that same thing.  But I'm not sure that is exactly what you want to do because you didn't specify in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to put the sheet name into the worksheet it corresponds to?  If so, the problem is that you are using `Select` instead of `Activate` to give the `Worksheet` focus.

The becomes a problem because you are using `Cells` without a qualifier so it refers to the `ActiveSheet` which has not been changed in your code.

Two solutions:

- Use `Activate` which will make `Cells` work like you want.
- Qualify the call to `Cells` by preceding it with a sheet object.

**Option 1**

```
Sub DataTransfer():
    Dim position As Integer, location(1 To 9) As String
    location(1) = "BC"
    location(2) = "Calgary"
    location(3) = "Edmonton"
    location(4) = "Major Projects"
    location(5) = "Minneapolis"
    location(6) = "Saskatchewan"
    location(7) = "Seattle"
    location(8) = "Toronto"
    location(9) = "Winnipeg"

    For position = 1 To 9
        Worksheets(location(position)).Activate
        Cells(1, 2).Value = location(position)
    Next position
End Sub
```

**Option 2**

```
Sub DataTransfer():
    Dim position As Integer, location(1 To 9) As String
    location(1) = "BC"
    location(2) = "Calgary"
    location(3) = "Edmonton"
    location(4) = "Major Projects"
    location(5) = "Minneapolis"
    location(6) = "Saskatchewan"
    location(7) = "Seattle"
    location(8) = "Toronto"
    location(9) = "Winnipeg"

    For position = 1 To 9
        'this line really does nothign now
        Worksheets(location(position)).Select

        Worksheets(location(position)).Cells(1, 2).Value = location(position)
    Next position
End Sub
```

I prefer Option 2 because it does not require activating the `Worksheet` first.  It should always be your goal to avoid Activating and Selecting when possible.  They slow things down and make code the opposite of robust.

Finally, as pointed out by @nutsch there are easier ways to do something simialr to this, but it's worth knowing why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, those codes worked liked a charm. But then again, when I copy-pasted the code into a new workbook today, it also ran as it was meant to. I'm really confused as to why the code would sometimes work and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a worksheet name issue. How many worksheets do you have that don't need updating? Could you do

```
dim sht as worksheet

for each sht in activeworkbook.sheets
 sht.cells(1,2)=sht.name
next
```